# ECS not starting tasks even though there is enough capacity

Tags: amazon-ecs

I've got a task definition that uses 977MB memory and 1024 CPU, using awsvpc networking:
[image: Task definition]

And I have EC2 instances provided by an Auto Scaling group tied to a Capacity Provider, already running 4 tasks across 4 instances:
[image: ECS Instances]

But when I launch 2 new tasks on top the 4 that are already running, they get stuck in "PROVISIONING" state. Despite what looks like enough memory and CPU to run the new tasks.

What could be going wrong and where can I look further to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

I was running t3a.small instances, but these have a limit of at most 2 network interfaces including the host. So you can only run one container on them. Limits are documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI

Comment: Ah, this is a frustrating limitation.  I thought an m6a.large would be able to pack 8 tasks, but it can only do 2!  I imagine the 3rd interface is already taken by the underlying instance.

Answer (score 0):

> these have a limit of at most 2 network interfaces

You can avoid the limit on ENI by setting the network mode of the task as bridge (which is the default).